# Can't run npm install on brand new create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have a very strange error when trying to create a react app using the create-react-app module. On my computer it is very easy to recreate the error:

```
npx create-react-app test-project --typescript
```

The project works fine. But if I delete the node_modules folder and do:

```
npm install
```

I get this error:

```
 npm install
    npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
    npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
    npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...3s4pkvleO6z4pcCFRth5v'

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/computer/.npm/_logs/2019-08-14T14_44_36_086Z-debug.log
```

Funny thing is, if I remove the "react-scripts" from the package.json file, npm install is succesfull - but of course the project doesn't work then.

I am using Node 12.8.0. And here are the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.17",
    "@types/node": "12.7.1",
    "@types/react": "16.9.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running

```
npm cache clean --force
```

But if you want to check if it is a viable solution before nuking the entire cache you can do:

```
npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

It forces npm to not use the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I clone your package.json and `npm install` work good 
using node v11.14.0 and npm 6.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried to clear this problem to use on the node v12.8.1.

But I could't solve it.

Finally, I down-graded node version to 10.16.3 LTS. :(

If you want to use 'create-react-app' that have no npm error, Just use node version **10.16.3** LTS.